# Getting the first available port in Haskell, in a platform-independent way

Tags: haskell, networking

I'd like to get the first available (unbound) port to be able to start a connection on it. Right now I'm using the [bind](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.3.2/docs/Network-Socket.html) function in the following way:

```
-- | Get a free port number.
getFreePort :: IO Integer
getFreePort = do
  sock <- socket AF_INET Stream defaultProtocol
  bind sock (SockAddrInet aNY_PORT iNADDR_ANY)
  port <- socketPort  sock
  close sock
  return (toInteger port)
```

But I'm not sure about the parameters I'm passing to `socket` and `bind`, and I also have to bind the socket only to extract its number and then close it again, which seems like a bit of overhead.

Can this be achieved in a better way?

Comment: A lot of internal functions? It just calls native `bind` with some prior sanity checking.

Comment: Use `bind` and use 0 for the port number?

Comment: At first I thought about avoiding `bind` because there are a lot of parameters I'm not sure how to fill in, and I have to `bind` and `close` a socket, which seems like overhead. I'll update the question with my current approach.

Comment: `bind()`'ing a socket to port 0 is the correct way to get a random available port from the OS. However, once you close the socket, the port is released back to the OS, so someone else may be able to grab the port before you can use it yourself.  If you need a port, it is usually because you are going to be using it soon, so don't close the socket that obtained the port, just use it.