# Why re-binding to a socket will fail randomly?

Tags: sockets, haskell, networking

This question is related to [a question about getting a free port in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45675403/2289983), where I included a `getFreePort` function that retrieved the first available port. This function works on a Windows system, but when I tried on my Linux box it fails randomly (the free port is reported as busy).

I've modified the function to try to re-bind to the free address, and it fails at random:

```
getFreePort :: IO Integer
getFreePort = do
  sock <- socket AF_INET Stream defaultProtocol
  bind sock (SockAddrInet aNY_PORT iNADDR_ANY)
  port <- socketPort sock
  close sock
  print "Trying to rebind to the sock"
  sock <- socket AF_INET Stream defaultProtocol
  bind sock (SockAddrInet port 0x0100007f)
  port <- socketPort sock
  close sock
  return (toInteger port)
```

I understand that there is a race condition about other process acquiring that port, but isn't this unlikely?

Comment: After obtaining a free port, why are you closing the socket that was used to obtain it?  Don't do that.  Just use that same socket, don't create and bind a new socket to the same port, that is indeed a race condition.  Closing the previous socket puts the port into a `TIME_WAIT` state that prevents it from being reused for a period of time unless you use the `SO_REUSEADDR`/`SO_REUSEPORT` socket option

Comment: Problem is that I have to pass the port number to two external processes that will communicate on that port. That's why I have to close it.

Comment: Why aren't those 2 processes obtaining ports for themselves and coordinating with each other? Why are you doing this in a 3rd process?  You can't obtain a port and then close it, and then expect the processes to be able to use it.  You need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Yes, it sounds ackward. But that was the way the two processes were designed. They expect a port number on which to communicate with each other. I cannot change that. An alternative might be to assign a random port number in some range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general remark, the pattern of `check if a resource is available and if so take it` is often an anti-pattern. Whenever you do that you run the risk that another process takes the resource after the check but before you actually acquire it yourself.

The only info you have after such a check is that the resource was not used at that particular point in time. It may or may not help you to guess the port's state in the future but the information you have is in no way binding at any later time. You cannot assume that because the resource was free at time `t` it will still be free at `t+dt`. Even if `dt` is very small. It's maybe a bit more likely that it will still be free when you ask *fast*. But that's just it - maybe a higher probability.

You should just try to acquire a resource and handle failure appropriately. The only way you can be sure a port was really free is when you just successfully opened it. Then you know it was indeed free. As soon as you close it all bets are off again.

I don't think you can ever safely check if a port is free in one process and then assume it still is free in another process. That does not make sense. It does not even make sense within the same process!

At the very least you would have to design a protocol that would go back and forth:

1. here's a port that was just free, try that
2. nope, it's taken now
3. ok, here's another one
4. nope, it's taken now
5. ok, here's another one
6. yep, got it, thanks

But that is pretty silly to begin with. The process that needs the port should just open it. When it already has the port open and not before, then it should communicate the port number to the other party.